# Macro return type and higher order functions

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

I am playing around with Scala macros using 2.10.0-M5 and I can't figure out why the compiler thinks the return type is `Any` rather than `List[Int]`. If I remove the call to map and just return the list (changing the last line of the macro to `c.Expr(list)`), it works as expected. Also, the macro does return a `List[Int]`, the compiler just doesn't know it.

Macro definition:

```
def test(s:String) = macro testImpl

def testImpl(c:Context)(s:c.Expr[String]):c.Expr[Any] = {
  import c.universe._
  val list = reify(List(1)).tree

  val function = reify((x:Int) => x).tree

  val res = 
    Apply(
      Select(
        list,
        newTermName("map")),
      List(function)
    )

  c.Expr(res)
}
```

Macro call:

```
val list:List[Int] = test("")
```

Error message:

```
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: List[Int]
[error]     val list:List[Int] = test("")
[error]                              ^
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the new macro system, but shouldn't your `testImpl` return `c.Expr[List[Int]]` rather than `c.Expr[Any]`?

Comment: In this case that would be an option. In my real code however, the return type depends on the parameter of the macro, so I don't know it in advance. Anyway, it does work with `c.Expr[Any]`, if I remove the call to map, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6155

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But if that was the case, wouldn't the compiler think the type is `List[Any]` rather than just `Any`?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I still don't understand the reason for the error. Updated the answer to remove the misleading hypothesis.

Comment: While you investigate this, do you have any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Doesn't look like a bug to me. It types the statement, which fails because `test("")`'s return type is `Any`. If the type of `list` hadn't been declared, then the second go at typer _after_ macro expansion would infer it to `List[Int]`.

Comment: How do you explain that it works without the call to map then? And how else would one write a macro whose return type varies with its argument? Specifying `c.Expr[Any]` as the return type works fine in other cases.

Comment: "If the type of list hadn't been declared, then the second go at typer after macro expansion would infer it to List[Int]" Have you tested any of these speculations? Because if you don't declare the type of list, it gets inferred to `Any`. I merely declared it to make the problem obvious.

Comment: There's definitely a bug, I just was afk the entire weekend, so didn't have a chance to take a closer look.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral It's intended that macros can expand to something that's a subtype of a macro def's return value.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's a bug. Should I open a ticket? Btw, I just tried with M6 and unsurprisingly it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to refer to the corresponding ticket. I'm afraid we won't be able to fix it by 2.10.0-final, but luckily there's a workaround mentioned in the ticket.